# On compositions of functions and their properties

Tags: analysis

Given:

$ f: X \longrightarrow Y\\ g: Y \longrightarrow Z $

and $g \circ f : X \longrightarrow Z $ is a bijection.

I want to analyse wether $f$ is an injection, a surjection or both (a bijection). I know the following: $g \circ f$ is a bijection, therefore $g \circ f$ has only one inverse image. It seems very intuitive to me, that under these circumstances $f$ must be injective, otherwise $f$ could have more than 1 inverse image (pre image).

For instance it could be that $f(x_1)=y=f(x_2)$ with $x_1 \neq x_2$ which would imply that: $(g\circ f)(x_1)=(g \circ f)(x_2)$

However, I have serious doubts that I am using the corrects laws and logic here when it comes to prove my thoughts.

If $f$ is injective, then $f(x)=f(x') \implies x'=x$ such that:
\begin{align}(g \circ f)(x)=(g \circ f)(x') &\iff g(f(x))=g(f(x'))  \\ & \implies f(x)=f(x') \tag{?} \\ &\implies x=x' \end{align}

Especially the term marked with ? seems very strange to me, it seems to me like that would imply that $g$ is injective to start with. Where are my flaws? do I need to discuss $g$ first in this composition before I can give informations about $f$?

How about this proof?

We know that $g \circ f$ is surjective, because it is bijective, this means that $\forall z \in Z \exists x \in X : z=g(f(x))$ Now if  $f$ is surjective that also means $\forall y \in Y \exists x \in X : f(x)=y $

thus we can say $z=g(y)$, how does this equation introduce a sufficient contradition when I know that $f$ is not surjective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: If $f$ is not injective then $gf$ is not injective either and consider $f\colon [0,1]\to [-1,1],\ x \to x$ and $g\colon [-1,1]\to [0,1],\ x \to |x|$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, it seems clear to me that this statement must hold, but how could I go from there on a formal proof?

Comment: If $f(x)=f(y)$ for $x \ne y$, then $gf(x)=gf(y)$.

Comment: Ah alright, I believe I have done that already in my opening post (see middle section). I understand that in this case that $f$ is not injective and neither is the composition $gf$. So I guess this is the 'best' attempt I can take to show that $f$ must be injective in order for the composition to be bijective.

Comment: Updated my post, maybe I can ask for another hint.

Answer (score 0):

u can say that$f(x)$ is equal to $f(x')$, given that $g(f(x))=g(f(x'))$ only when $ g$ is One-one

Comment: My statements from above would make much more sense to me if I would add that f is injective if and only if g is injective.